# Why is level icon now orange in Evil Genius 2?

Tags: evil-genius-2

In Evil Genius 2, the icons for the levels (B, 1, 2, 3, 4, Binoculars) are usually Yellow.

One of mine has turned Orange.

Why? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Found out.

I don't remember any notification and it was hard to spot.

I was raided by a Super-Agent called Symmetry. She left behind a small device on the wall which was a network security jammer. Once I removed these, the level icon turned yellow again.